# Missing Microsoft.Windows.Design.dll

Tags: c#, wpf

I downloaded a project that has a reference to Microsoft.Windows.Design.dll, but it's not on my system. Where can I get this package?

```
using Microsoft.Windows.Design.PropertyEditing;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That namespace is typically found in the `Microsoft.Windows.Design.Interaction.dll` assembly, not `Microsoft.Windows.Design.dll`.

For example, the [`NewItemFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.design.propertyediting.newitemfactory.aspx) class:

> Namespace:  Microsoft.Windows.Design.PropertyEditing
>
> Assembly:  Microsoft.Windows.Design.Interaction (in **Microsoft.Windows.Design.Interaction.dll**)